# Expected number of draws to get n equally likely outcomes m times each.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, computational-complexity, coupon-collector

There's a bag containing n distinct objects. Keeping track of the outcomes, one object is drawn from the bag, and put back in. Repeating this operation until each of the $n$ objects has been seen at least $m$ times, what is the expected number of draws ?

The way i found to compute this involves representing it as a Markov Chain:

The current state is a list $l$ of m numbers, $l_i$ being the number of objects drawn exactly $i$ times for $0 ≤ i < m$. As the state doesn't account for object drawn m times or more, drawing an object that belong to this group leads you to the same state.

[Example with n=3, m=2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pz5P0.png)

We can then remove the transitions that keep you in the same state and instead take into account the expected number of draws to leave that state.

[Same example without loops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xroN.png)

The expected number of draws to reach last state can then be defined recursively as:

$$f(\text{last state}) = 0$$

$$f(state) =$$
$$\text{Expected number of draws to leave the state}$$
$$+$$
$$\sum_{\text{next state}}{\text{probability of transition to next state}* \text{f(next state)}}$$

[Python implementation](https://github.com/MartinDlry/misc-python-code/blob/main/expected_draws.py)

Now comes my problem: doing it this way require to go through every possible state, and the number of states is ${n+m \choose m}$, so it grows exponentially with $m$.

Is there a way to do it more efficiently ?
If not, is there a way to get an approximation more efficiently ?